# IntelliJ Run Configuration for Spring Boot apps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I do not change run configuration unless reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA and I am not sure if I set the run config properly.

[Configuration Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkP4r.png)

Could you pls clarify me about the following issue based on the attached dialog:

**1.** SHould I use SPring Boot or Application Template of Run config for a Spring Boot app? Or is both of them are ok?

**2.** Which field should I fill in order to set the run config properly?

Comment: Use the Spring Boot configuration. You don't need to fill any fields, it will work out of the box if you click on the Run button in editor: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder But in SpringBoot config, Main class field is required. Then should I set that field as `com.mycompany.Application` e.g.>?

Comment: @CrazyCoder And, what about Application config? Should I use it just for Java and console apps?

Comment: The fields are configured automatically per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html. Yes, it's for plain Java apps.

Comment: I tried, but Main class field is required. If you have a spring boot project, could you please check and then writes the steps you followed? My it be related to the version of my IntelliJ? I use the latest version

Comment: IDE should help you to select the correct main class: https://i.imgur.com/9pMxG0z.png.

Comment: I cannot vote up as I do not enough repo. Any vote up for my question pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Spring Boot configuration, and set the class containing the main method as the class that is created automatically by IntelliJ when you create a new Spring Initializr project. But usually, this is created automatically.

See the attached image for the details. Notice the main class field points to the file DemoApplication.

[image: IntelliJ Spring Boot Debug Configuration]

Comment: I cannot vote up as I do not enough repo. Any vote up for my question pls?